# Filter array with multiples level

Tags: javascript, arrays

i need to go through an array of objects to compare 2 values.
This is my array:

```
    const data = [{
            "uid": "6448ae4a79",
            "title": "New Group",
            "slug": "new-group",
            "items": [
              {
                "uid": "8602b1cf1f",
                "title": "New sub group",
                "slug": "new-sub-group",
                "items": [
                  {
                    "uid": "8b6f962ff1",
                    "_id": "5d9b453285a8982000b4a9e6",
                    "title": "fsds",
                    "choices": [
                      {
                        "uid": "a5ccb273a2",
                        "_id": "5d9b453285a8982000b4a9eb",
                        "type": null,
                        "text": "sd",
                        "label": null,
                        "value": null
                      },
                      {
                        "uid": "8ab0d45386",
                        "_id": "5d9b453285a8982000b4a9e8",
                        "type": null,
                        "text": "sdwewe",
                        "label": null,
                        "value": null
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    "uid": "290db30b53",
                    "_id": "5d9b699185a8982000b4aa1d",
                    "title": "czxczxc",
                    "logic": {
                      "viewControl": [
                        {
                          "action": "lock",
                          "group": "6448ae4a79",
                          "subGroup": "8602b1cf1f",
                          "question": "8b6f962ff1",
                          "equalTo": "8ab0d45386"
                        }
                      ]
                    },
                    "choices": [
                      {
                        "uid": "3cce36d426",
                        "_id": "5d9b699185a8982000b4aa1f",
                        "type": 0,
                        "text": "wqewq",
                        "label": "dsfsd",
                        "value": null
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
   }]
```

I have to compare items.items.logic.viewControl[0].equalTo with choices.uid. Eg: "equalTo": "8ab0d45386" === "uid": "8ab0d45386".

How can I do this? I tried filter, map and foreach and I couldn't do it at all

Comment: _"I tried filter, map and foreach and I couldn't do it at all"_ - Post at least one of your approaches and we might be able to help.

Comment: @Andreas https://jsfiddle.net/dz41v5un/

Comment: what result are you looking for? You're trying to recursively search for any object with a uid that matches?

Comment: In the question itself -> [How do I write a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @zfrisch I'm trying to find in the array a choice with a value other than null. The items[0].items[1] will be locked until a choice with uid equal to equalTo has a value other than null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal to check that viewControl.equalTo - is one of choices (from different items) - so the solution may look like this:

1. Go over all items & collect `choices.uid`
2. Go over all viewControls & check that `choices.uid` exists.

```js
const data = [{
    "uid": "6448ae4a79",
    "title": "New Group",
    "slug": "new-group",
    "items": [
        {
            "uid": "8602b1cf1f",
            "title": "New sub group",
            "slug": "new-sub-group",
            "items": [
                {
                    "uid": "8b6f962ff1",
                    "_id": "5d9b453285a8982000b4a9e6",
                    "title": "fsds",
                    "choices": [
                        {
                            "uid": "a5ccb273a2",
                            "_id": "5d9b453285a8982000b4a9eb",
                            "type": null,
                            "text": "sd",
                            "label": null,
                            "value": null
                        },
                        {
                            "uid": "8ab0d45386",
                            "_id": "5d9b453285a8982000b4a9e8",
                            "type": null,
                            "text": "sdwewe",
                            "label": null,
                            "value": null
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "uid": "290db30b53",
                    "_id": "5d9b699185a8982000b4aa1d",
                    "title": "czxczxc",
                    "logic": {
                        "viewControl": [
                            {
                                "action": "lock",
                                "group": "6448ae4a79",
                                "subGroup": "8602b1cf1f",
                                "question": "8b6f962ff1",
                                "equalTo": "8ab0d45386"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "choices": [
                        {
                            "uid": "3cce36d426",
                            "_id": "5d9b699185a8982000b4aa1f",
                            "type": 0,
                            "text": "wqewq",
                            "label": "dsfsd",
                            "value": null
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}];

// 1. Collect choices.uid
const choicesUids = {};
data.forEach((d) => {
   d.items.forEach((i1) => {
    i1.items.forEach((i2) => {
      i2.choices.forEach(c => {choicesUids[c.uid]=true})
    });
  });
});

// 2. Check the logic
data.forEach((d, ix0) => {
   d.items.forEach((i1, ix1)=>{
    i1.items.forEach((i2, ix2)=>{
      if(i2.logic && i2.logic.viewControl) {
        i2.logic.viewControl.forEach((vc, ix3)=>{
          console.log(`data[${ix0}].items[${ix1}].items[${ix2}].logic.viewControl[${ix3}].equalTo:${vc.equalTo} - is ${choicesUids[vc.equalTo]?'GOOD':'BAD'}`);
        });
       }
    });
  });
});
```

OUTPUT:
`data[0].items[0].items[1].logic.viewControl[0].equalTo:8ab0d45386 - is GOOD`